# How can I fix this error I am getting when trying to create a Web3AuthModalPack instance?

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, account-abstraction, safe

I am trying to create a Web3AuthModalPack instance using the Web3Auth pack. I am following this guide: https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/web3auth
I am getting this error when running ts-node-esm web3Auth.ts:

```
file:///Users/joeabourizk/P2P-Wallet/AppMobile/safe/web3Auth.ts:2
```

import { CHAIN_NAMESPACES, WALLET_ADAPTERS } from "@web3auth/base";
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'CHAIN_NAMESPACES' not found. The requested module '@web3auth/base' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@web3auth/base';
const { CHAIN_NAMESPACES, WALLET_ADAPTERS } = pkg;

```
at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `web3Auth` pack was deprecated recently in favor of the [`safeAuth`](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/guides/safe-auth) pack developed in collaboration with Web3Auth. Please head towards our updated documentation for a [complete reference](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/reference/safeauthpack).

Hope it helps,
Louis